# How can I mask values for black outline around imagery using ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: raster, arcgis-pro, imagery

I pulled some NAIP imagery off the web. There is a black outline that I am trying to get rid of around each image. I tried to change the symbology to not include the zero values for each band but it is not getting rid of the black outline. Is there another way to filter out the zero values in my image?

Here are a picture of what I mean:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

In the Symbology pane, click the Mask tab. Then check on "Display background value", set it to the corresponding RGB values for the black collar (e.g., 0,0,0), and set the color to No color. You can also filter out NoData values in this same menu.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Don't know how I didn't see that. Appreciate your response